# Node.js - Express - Static js file not loading in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, template-engine

I know this is a ripetitive question but I've tried all kind of tutorials and followed all suggestions here on stack and elsewhere, my issue is not resolved.

I'm trying to build a simple static website with node.js and express to take advantage of the added server-side functionalities like fs, database integration and so forth but using old style css, html and js.

I know node.js likes using template engines (jade, ejs) but this is not my case, I need a simple index.html file with a script tag at the bottom for my javascript logic that is stored in a static folder /public (to separate concerns).
For now init.js only contains a console.log for testing.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" scr="/public/init.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I've followed guides about express's use of static files and tried every possible combination of the following method (which for clarity is in a file called server.js that is node.js main file for my project):

```
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This resolved loading the css files as now my page loads css correctly, with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/style.css">
```

I've also tried many combinations of the script tag, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="/init.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="/public/init.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="./public/init.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="../public/init.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="init.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

My question is why my /public/init.js is not loaded? I can clearly point to it by typing the address, which will show me the content of the file as text:

```
http://localhost:9000/public/init.js
```

I've checked the network tab in the browser's dev tools and init.js is totally ignored.
Is there any security policy that's stopping it to load?
Thank you.

Comment: In your script tags, you have written `scr` instead of  `src`, is it also the case in your real file ?

Comment: Yes, I'm very sorry I've bothered you guys!Thank you for this!
While we're at it, have you got any suggestion about how to send variables and data to plain html without using a template engine?
I understand how jade/ejs handle variables and data and I also know I can build a REST API to reproduce the same thing with http requests in plain html (old style), but is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you misspelled `scr` it shoudl be `src`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/init.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: I have no words to describe my shame!!!!!!!!THANK YOU, I didn't really notice that and it was killing me!!!